# Redirecting in a class that implements the ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

```
public class AdministratorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            EFUserRepository repo = new EFUserRepository();
            var user = repo.FindUserByUserName(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            if (user.UserRole.Name == "Administrator")
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(//Redirect to the original action they tried to enter?
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //redirect to the "Home/Index" area.
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble redirecting to an action from within this OnActionExecuting method. Also, how would I redirect the user to their original intended action if they are fully authorized.

This `[Administrator]` attribute is going to be placed on many different controllers, so I have to have a way to redirect to the appropriate ActionResult they were trying to reach.

Comment: Can you not use the `Authorize` attribute? `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`?

Comment: I have my own custom membership system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is, for a GET at least, to url-encode the requested url and include it. For example, for SO if we start on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182675/redirecting-in-a-class-that-implements-the-actionfilterattribute) as anonymous, and click login, we are taken to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f7182675%2fredirecting-in-a-class-that-implements-the-actionfilterattribute
```

The same would work for a redirect; once you have completed login, check for a `returnurl` parameter, and back you go.

You should, however, check that the target url is either *relative* (same-site), or absolute to the *current* site or another site you own/etc ([see OWASP for details](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4) - in particular "Example Scenarios").